# Save Excel range as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, save-as

I'd like to 'save as' a specific sheet or specific range to pdf.

I tried implementing a range into my code.

Here is what I've been working with:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  "c:\Book1.pdf", Quality:= _
  xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: the code works for me, what part is missing? If you want to use a specific range, move the range to a new sheet and print that sheet to pdf before deleting it, no?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that will work fine, however the end result I'm shooting for will be completely automated, so rather than creating a whole bunch of sheets then worrying about deleting them, is there a way I can just select a range then save that to pdf?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you have the code, just use a range instead of `activesheet`

e.g. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:H28").ExportAsFixedFormat ...`

Comment: Thanks that worked. WOW! I really need to purchase a vba book.